# Cannot getJudul from getter setter modal

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am building a recyclerview, the recyclerview is already display data from the database.

I want the data in the recyclerview to be clicked and go to another activity to see the detailed data.

The problem is that when implementing on onCreateViewHolder, I can't call getJudul from Getter and Setter. When calling Getter Setter there is a message "cannot resolve the getJudul method"

Here my model

```
public class BeritaPagModel {
    String idberita, judul;

    public BeritaPagModel() {
    }

    public String getIdberita() {
        return idberita;
    }

    public void setIdberita(String idberita) {
        this.idberita = idberita;
    }

    public String getJudul() {
        return judul;
    }

    public void setJudul(String judul) {
        this.judul = judul;
    }
}
```

My View Holder

```
public class BeritaPagViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public BeritaPagViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iclicklistener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                iclicklistener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setItem(Context ctx, String judul){
        TextView ijudul = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beritapag_judul_itemlist);
        ijudul.setText(judul);
    }

    public interface ClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);}
    private BeritaPagViewHolder.ClickListener iclicklistener;
    public void setOnClickListener(BeritaPagViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener){
        iclicklistener = clickListener;
    }
}
```

My main fragment

```
iref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("berita");
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build();
        DatabasePagingOptions<BeritaPagModel> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<BeritaPagModel>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(iref, config, BeritaPagModel.class)
                .build();

        iadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<BeritaPagModel, BeritaPagViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BeritaPagViewHolder beritaPagViewHolder, int i, @NonNull BeritaPagModel beritaPagModel) {
                beritaPagViewHolder.setItem(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        beritaPagModel.getJudul()
                        );
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state){
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        iswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;
                    case LOADED:
                        iswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;
                    case FINISHED:
                        iswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;
                    case ERROR:
                        retry();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BeritaPagViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_beritapag_itemlist, parent, false);
                BeritaPagViewHolder beritaPagViewHolder = new BeritaPagViewHolder(itemView);

                beritaPagViewHolder.setOnClickListener(new BeritaPagViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Klik sekali", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        final String curJudul = getItem(position).getJudul();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Klik lamaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                return beritaPagViewHolder;

            }
        };
        irecyclerView.setAdapter(iadapter);

        iswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                iadapter.refresh();
            }
        });
        return irootview;
    }
```

[Sceenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA23u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure #getItem(position) return BeritaPagModel

**if it returns Object, you have to cast it as BeritaPagModel:**

`((BeritaPagModel)getItem(position)).getJudul();`

**If it is the above does not work, try click file -> invalidate cache and restart**

**EDIT:**

You may try to move your code to the #onBindViewHolder() method, you will get the BeritaPagModel object reference there.

I have also found an example for your reference: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-pagination-in-android-using-firebaseui-library-1d7fe1a75704

Comment: thank you for the response. I've tried it, I added, final String curJudul = ((BeritaPagModel)getItem(position)).getJudul(); but but still an error. Inconvertible type cannot cast 'com.google.firebase.database.Datasnapshot' to 'com.example.myproject.BeritaPagination.BeritaPagModel'. What should i do, please help.

Comment: You may try to move your code to the #onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: Okay i will try it